# My very own tags

Tags: discussion, tagging, data-explorer

The badge Taxonomist is given when a user creates a tag which reaches 50 questions. This means that somewhere in the system there is an assignment for the user who created a tag.

Is there any possible way to find out what tags I have created over the years, and how they are doing now?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think there is a way:

- [How can I query SEDE for tags I've created?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69812/214632)

It turns out that tag authorship is for private consumption only.

Comment: Shame. I wanted to know.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose that using something like [PostHistoryType.Id=2](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/59233/list-posthistorytypes) and [PostType.id=5](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/edit/152567) you could find a list of *tag-wikis* you have created.
Try for example [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/84003/posts-by-a-given-user?PostType=5&UserId=622) for a somewhat similar query (although that query was designed for answers and questions, so the results do not look that fine for tag-wikis. There is definitely a space for improvement; perhaps there already is a query for this.)

Many users also create tag-wiki, when they create a tag. If you did so, then this should be a subset of the list of tags you have created.

Of course, this is not the same thing as what you wanted, but it might be some approximation (at least in some cases.)

---

[One of the answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69812/how-can-i-query-sede-for-tags-ive-created/114365#114365) in the post linked in Arthur Fischer's posts mentions this query:
[The tags where the oldest question with this tag was created by a given user](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/54505/the-tags-where-the-oldest-question-with-this-tag-was-created-by-given-user?user=622). It can also be considered as an approximation of the list of tags created by a user.

The above query only looks at the oldest *question* with the given tag. Here is another query which also looks into the PostHistory: [Tags created by a specific user](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1230221/tags-created-by-a-specific-user?userid=622). This query also returns the tags which have been deleted since the creation. For example, the tags which were created just as a consequence of a typo in the tag name. Still, the query is not completely reliable, as the question where the tag was created might have been deleted (and the PostHistory table does not keep the data about deleted questions).

Some queries related to getting some information about the tag creator can be found here: [Can you tell who created a tag](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25038). I will also add the link to this question: [What is the name of the (now removed) tag for which this Taxonomist badge has been awarded?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32935) It shows that the situation can be a bit more complicated - for example, merging two tags changes the revision history, so in such cases the data from SEDE might show something different from the situation at the time.

---

You can find at least one tag you have created - namely the one for which you have obtained [the taxonomist badge](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist?userid=622).

Comment: You could also try what happens, if you look for PostType.id=5 and PostTypePostHistoryType.Id=1. (This PostHistoryType is called Initial Title.) But I suppose this returns the first tag-wiki editor, not the tag creator. I do not have much time to experiment with this at the moment. :-(

Comment: The query about tags where the oldest question is some particular user returned [tag:forcing] and [tag:infinitary-combinatorics] for the OP. (2 rows returned in 91807 ms)

Comment: Martin, I'm mainly interested in the tags I created three years ago when the site was new. But also in the general statistics of how many tags I have created. I suppose that the right way to find out would be to search all the histories of questions and find out when was the first time someone edited a tag into existence; but that overlooks deleted tags, as well tag merges (my Taxonomist badge was given for a now-merged tag).

Comment: The [History](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/84497/revisions) for tag-wiki `forcing` shows creation by Community in 2011.

Comment: @hardmath It seems that he created the [tag-excerpt](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/84498/revisions).

Comment: Various SEDE queries related to tags can be found also [in the Tagging chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=query&room=3740).