# How to find out a tag which I created?

Tags: discussion, support, tagging

Once I have created a tag, but I have forgotten which tag it was. How do I find out which one it is? So that at least I can use that tag in my question.

Comment: Is it possible to add a link to a meta thread, or encouragement to post on meta first, to the page https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags? Or must pages in the help center be identical across all SE sites?

Comment: After Jyrki Lahtonen's post I found out that by searching for [your username in  tagging chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=user152715&user=&room=3740) you can find [when the tag in question was created](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2018/1/28). But this worked only because you have created the tag in *your own question* not in question posted by another user.

Comment: While the tag is gone now, let me also point out that you should *never* **ever** ***ever*** retag 50 questions in a matter of hours without at least bringing the topic on meta. Every retag bumps questions to the main page, and this is taking precious virtual estate from other questions. Let alone if *all* your retags are to your own questions, as that would just seem like a greedy  way to get a badge and a few more votes. (Even if your intention here was an honest one, this is just how I would see it if I had seen that action on time.)

Comment: It seems that comments and answer here are more about best practices when creating tags rather than about the original question whether it is possible to find out which tags user has created. This question seems to be very close to an older question (posted by Asaf): [My very own tags](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11986) (Almost a duplicate - although there is a slight difference, since from the comments it seems that the OP is interested in situation when the tag was later removed or synonymized.)

Comment: @Martin: The question was asked a few hours before the synonym took effect. So it's not quite different after all, perhaps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's [not possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/82/295232) in a straightforward way, unless you received the [Taxonomist badge](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist) because it was used in 50 or more questions. You don't seem to have that badge, so you're out of luck.

---

**Update**: based on [this SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/811034/probable-tag-creations-for-a-specific-user?UserId=152715) I just created, it's likely to be [siegel-modular-forms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/siegel-modular-forms) — which you just added to 52 questions. I'm not sure if this is appropriate behaviour. Are you **absolutely sure** the tag is appropriate for all of those questions?

Comment: Okay, I was trying to earn that badge at least by my questions.

Comment: Although I find this situation a bit ridiculous, one has to admit that the site does encourage users to chase down the "next badge".

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Taxonomist is never offered as an option for the next badge AFAIK.

Comment: In my opinion, doing something like that is grounds for suspension. It literally undermines the work that many people (myself included) have put into the tagging system. Which—admittedly—is not even close to perfect. But people come and shit on this work just to get a frigging badge. For fucks sake.

Comment: I will just asks whether I correctly understand the query in your answer - it looks for tags where the oldest post in the tag was made by the given users. So if I created tag in somebody's else question, it won't be there. And I will be listed there, if some of my questions was the one were someone else created a tag. Is that correct?

Comment: @MartinSleziak correct. [This](http://data.stackexchange.com/biology/query/196683/tag-ownership-taxonomist) is actually a better query.

Answer (score 7):

I somehow suspect that you are talking about the tag [siegel-modular-forms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/siegel-modular-forms).

I'm sure you honestly thought this to be a service to the community, and, as the software allowed you to create one, you may be a bit surprised by what feedback you get here ....... But, the way our culture has evolved over the years is that nowadays, more or less normatively, new tags should be cleared and discussed in [a meta thread dedicated for that very purpose](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27653/11619).

Other points:

- Your tag may be defensible, at least it's a good enough idea to warrant serious consideration. But, please plead the case in meta before creating new tags. I think you can make a reasonable case, and the suggestion will be taken seriously. Not the least because you seem to have created [an informative tag wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/siegel-modular-forms/info).
- More often than not a new tag is created by an eager noob hunting for a taxonomist badge. Because such a user typically A) doesn't know much math, and B) has not familiarized themselves with our tagging system, such tags are usually abysmal, and removing them is a lot of work. Therefore our knee-jerk reaction to a new tag out of the blue is "Oh, no. Another one of those."
- If you create a tag for the purposes of earning a taxonomist badge, and add the tag anywhere it might fit, then ... you deserve all the heat you are gonna get. Earning such a badge is meant to take time. Just create a tag, and wait. If it is good enough others will begin to use it as well, and then you get your badge. Getting a badge in the old-fashioned way of earning it (as opposed to clicking "edit" 50 times) feels much better!

---

Taking off my moderator hat and donning a [dictator's outfit](https://www.google.com/search?q=dictator+outfit&tbm=isch) instead:

- If I only could, I would forbid creation of new tags by means other than group clearance in meta.
- I would most certainly forbid anyone not yet in (or out of) grad school from creating a new tag simply because such people don't know much math at all.
- Actually I would also forbid people out of grad school from creating new tags unless they have cleared it in meta. This applies to myself as well as most of the others. I have not paid that much attention to what makes our tagging system work as well as it does, so I don't trust my own judgement (but I often need to deal with the consequences of a misguidedly created tag).
- This is IMNSHO a job for veterans of the site. But, they are actually a bunch of reasonable folks! It's not like they would steal your good ideas for new tags. They have spent a lot of time making it work, and will gladly elaborate on their objections (if any).

Comment: Wait, as a postdoc, I'm out of grad school... what does that mean? (I think you mean post-bachelor academia, not just grad school, though. I'm just being picky.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information and you are right that I have found out later on that it's siegel modular form