# What is the name of the (now removed) tag for which this Taxonomist badge has been awarded?

Tags: discussion, tagging, badges

In the [list of awardees of the Taxonomist badge](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist), [Yujie Zha](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/379853/yujie-zha) has been awarded this badge for a "no longer available" tag.  I wonder what's the name of this removed tag.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My best guess would be [fubini](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fubini) - which was later renamed to [fubini-tonelli-theorems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fubini-tonelli-theorems), see the revision history of the questions 3251436 [Why this function is not integrable](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3251436/revisions) and the details below.

---

These queries cannot be considered completely reliable - since we do not have data about the past revisions of deleted posts in [SEDE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info) - but there are some queries to find tags created in the past. (Such queries are sometimes [mentioned in the Tagging chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=query&room=3740).) See also: [Can you tell who created a tag](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25038) and [My very own tags](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11986).

- [Tags created by a specific user](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1230221/tags-created-by-a-specific-user?userid=379853)
- [Questions which had the given tag (including the editor who added it)](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1105163/questions-which-had-the-given-tag-including-the-editor-who-added-it?tagname=fubini-tonelli-theorems)

---

The situation with the tags [fubini-tonelli-theorems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fubini-tonelli-theorems) is a bit more complex.

The tag [fubini](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fubini) was [created in June 2019](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740?m=50566084#50566084). The tag [fubini-tonelli-theorems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fubini-tonelli-theorems) was [created in July 2020](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740?m=55022048#55022048) and the tag [fubini](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fubini) was merged into this tag [in September 2020](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3740/conversation/changing-fubini-to-fubini-tonelli-theorems). And when the tags were merged, all occurrences of [fubini](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fubini) were replaced by [fubini-tonelli-theorems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fubini-tonelli-theorems) - and the tag was also changed in the revision history. (At the same time, the original tag (fubini) was removed.) The deleted questions are an exception - as you can see [some deleted questions are still tagged (fubini)](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/883845/deleted-questions-with-a-given-tag?Tagname=fubini).

So the tag called [fubini-tonelli-theorems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fubini-tonelli-theorems) exists - but the Taxonomist badge is probably for the [fubini](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fubini), which was removed.